# Power shell script for Creating Project in Azure DevOps with Version control and work Iteam Proccess

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

Please some one  help me with the Power shell script which can  Creating Project in Azure DevOps with  Version control and work Item Process.

Comment: Please have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/project?view=azure-cli-latest#az-devops-project-create

Answer (score 0):

As **`@MarkusMeyer`** has mentioned, you can call the related Azure CLI to create a new project with the specified Source control type and Process.

Normally, you can do following below steps:

1. Open a PowerShell window.
2. Login to your Azure DevOps organization using the "**`az devops login`**" command.

   ```
   az devops login --org https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/
   ```
3. Provide your PAT (Personal Access Token) as the authentication.
4. Create a new project using the "**`az devops project create`**" command.

   ```
   az devops project create --name {ProjectName} --process {ProcessName} --source-control {git|tfvc} --visibility {private|public}
   ```

[image]

In addition, you also can call the Azure DevOps REST API ([**Projects - Create**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)) in the PowerShell script to create the new project.